# DateTimepicker is inserting wrong format in my mdf database file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

So I'm using DateTimePicker in my vb project, I have set my "CustomFormat" in my properties to be "MM-dd-yyyy" format and I've also set my "Format" to be "Custom" so that I can use my custom date format but whenever I insert it to my mdf database file which has a column of "expiration" the column displays to be a "dd-MM-yyyy" and not "MM-dd-yyyy", my database file is not following the format of my DateTimePicker. my "expiration" column datatype in my DB is "DATE"

Comment: Use SQL parameters with the correct DbType set to insert data into the database. That way, the date does not get messed up by mis-treating it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `DateTimePicker` is not inserting the wrong format into your database. The format of the control is irrelevant to your database. It is only relevant to the user looking at the control. No matter what that format is, the `Value` property of the control is type `DateTime` and that is a binary value with no format.  It is that value that you should be inserting into your database, into a column that has an appropriate data type, e.g. `datetime2`, and not a text-based data type, e.g. `varchar`.

If you do that then the database will contain a binary value too, with no format again. What you see in SQL Server Management Studio is, just like in your own application, a text representation of the date/time value. It can be formatted however the application chooses, but that doesn't change the underlying binary value.

Inserting data from a `DateTimePicker` into a SQL Server database would look something like this:

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString),
      command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person (Name, DateOfBirth) VALUES (@Name, @DateOfBirth)", connection)
    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = nameTextBox.Text
        .Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateOfBirthPicker.Value.Date
    End With

    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: @goldflakes, FYI, niceties like thanking people directly are discouraged on this site. It's supposed to be about the facts and just the facts. If you find an answer or comment helpful then you should upvote it and that is thanks enough.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all databases use their own internal Date structure for storing dates. You can't change that. When you pass a date in (hopefully as a date object, not a formatted string) it is interpreted into the internal structure and stored.

What you can do however is control how the date is formatted for output when you handle the value that is returned when you query the database.